# Google Apps Script: How to get number of active UrlFetchApp request (same as $.active in jQuery)?

Tags: google-apps-script, urlfetch

I have a custom function which makes a UrlFetchApp request to an API. This custom function is called multiple times at once, so multiple UrlFetchApp request is made.

I want to know when all the request is completed or the number of active request.

Pseudo Code

```
function myFunction(param){
    UrlFetchApp request
    Check if any active request // I need this part of the code
        do something
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: From a separate instance, there isn't a way to track how many `UrlFetchApp.fetch()` calls are still running. In the same instance, that instance is only performing the `fetch` call, and will not execute more code while fetching. If you're worried about quota overrun, design a gate on the calls to myFunction such that only 100 will be made in any given X second timeframe. If able, consider first building the individual requests and then using a batch call on the request array, i.e. `UrlFetchApp.fetchAll()`

Comment: yes, thanks. I think I need to change my approach.

Comment: if it is a custom function, make it return an array when given array input. This is discussed in apps script documentation.